# Azure EventHub trigger function process slow

Tags: performance, azure, azure-eventhub

I have Azure EventHub trigger function with app service plan (P2V2 tier with 8 instances) that need to process 2.4M messages in 30 minutes(1333 message/s) as expected. From beginning the function reach ~1200 messages/s, but by time when message remaining from EventHub not a lot, function begin process very slow ~500 ~200 ~100 messages/s. I also change app service plan to S3 but result still as same.
My question is there any solution for azure function always process high throughput(~1200 messages/s)?

Comment: You could try to change the host.json property.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-trigger?tabs=csharp#functions-2x-and-higher

Comment: How many partitions are there? Have you tried increasing the batch size?